# How to make while loop of SQL result to be defined loop?

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

I have some trouble of my code that using while loop, here is the code :

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_row($rskutnonindihome)){
    if(angka($row[2])==""){
        echo '<td class="d1">0</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td class="d1">' . angka($row[2]) . '</td>';
    }
    $totalNIH = $totalNIH+$row[2];
    $total = $total+$row[2];    
}
```

Im using this while loop of SQL Result in the data table in each row, what the problem is this SQL Result is dynamic and it makes the table row into a mess . 
When it's not filtered, the total row is 3, but when its filtered the total row is 2. So what I want is to make this while loop to be static, so it will looping for 3 times of loop. I'm tried this method but it won't work :

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_row($rskutnonindihome) < 3 ){
    if(angka($row[2])==""){
        echo '<td class="d1">0</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td class="d1">' . angka($row[2]) . '</td>';
    }
    $totalNIH = $totalNIH+$row[2];
    $total = $total+$row[2];    
}
```

**the SQL Result is :** 0 and its not looping

Comment: What output table do you actually expect here, and what does the current one look like?

Comment: so the current on look like this : https://imgur.com/rzU1Gdp

Comment: what i expected is the while loop will be 3 times of loop, so if the result of angka($row[2])=="") it will be 0 on the right of 76 value like in the table photo

Comment: https://imgur.com/3GlQds0

Comment: use a `for` from 1 to 3 and fetch the data inside the for